# Is there any API for github registering/joining?

Tags: git, api, github, github-api, user-registration

I was looking to register a user on **GitHub** through an API probably by running a script, but could not find it.

Kindly help me if there is any such APIs to register/join a user in GitHub.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is a way. To use API you have to be authorized and to be authorized you have to be already registered.

Comment: Is it just with GitHub or every other platforms?

Comment: There're not so much other platforms with API. There is Gitlab and there is Bitbucket. I'm sure the situation is the same everywhere. Nobody wants to be spammed with automatic user creation.

Comment: @PreethamSridhar your question can be rephrased as "Is it possible to create thousands of bogus Github accounts with a script ?". All sites go to extremes to *prevent* this, which is why you have to go through a Captcha *and* an email validation before you can subscribe to *any* site

Comment: @PreethamSridhar on the other hand, if the question is "Can I add users to an organization through a script?" yes, you can [add already registeres members to an organization](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/#add-or-update-organization-membership)

Answer (score 3):

No there is not (as is the case with most APIs)
You can run `curl https://api.github.com` to view endpoints GitHub provides.

As a general rule, sites won't allow the automation of account creation as it gives an easy avenue for bot creation.
The GitHub signup page includes a captcha to stop this - so you can see how a registration API would negate this security feature.